# Regex to capture a sentence between two strings

Tags: regex, email

Need  help in writing regex to capture the strings between two words.
Below is the proof point logs for which i need to capture the entire subject which can have space, special character, may or maynot have double quotes

Attempted to extract between two words `subject=` and `spamscore`

> Oct  4 05:56:32 m0001280 filter_instance1[29132]: rprt s=2dcdnyveuh m=1 x=2dcdnyveuh-1 mod=mail cmd=msg module=pdr rule=pass action=continue attachments=0 rcpts=1 routes=default_inbound size=79291 guid=LkvQgKjeRdwsasaddt
>    hdr_mid=<0.1.C1.766.adsdDC.0@omp.hello.com> qid=v94Au9Vj022820 hops-ip=X1.1X.11.X subject=hello world  spamscore virusname= duration=0.661 elapsed=1.049

For this we do have regex to capture

```
(?P<email_subject>(?<=subject=)(.*)(?=spam))
```

But this gets tricky, as in some log format we don't have a word `spamscore`. please find another sample log below

> Oct  4 05:56:32 m0001280 filter_instance1[29132]: rprt s=2dcdnyveuh m=1 x=2dcdnyveuh-1 mod=mail cmd=msg module=pdr rule=pass action=continue attachments=0 rcpts=1 routes=default_inbound size=79291 guid=LkvQgKjeRdwsasaddt
>   hdr_mid=<0.1.C1.766.adsdDC.0@omp.hello.com> qid=v94Au9Vj022820 hops-ip=X1.1X.11.X subject="hello !@@@#@42 43 (saadxasD)"  virusname= duration=0.661 elapsed=1.049

What is the best way to capture the subject without really depending on `spamscore` or `virusname` or double quotes as a delimiter in regular expression?

Comment: You'll have to provide some condition as to what ends the subject. Is it `anyword=`?

Comment: How about [`(?<=subject=).*?(?=\s*(?:\w+=|spamscore))`](https://regex101.com/r/I1tLFz/2) ?

Comment: `subject="?\K[^"]*?(?="?(?:\s+(?:spamscore\s+)?\w+=|$))` should match everything you need including removing `"` from the subject

Comment: Thanks @Gurman   for the solution . just solution worked perfectly  fine. Regex (?P<email_subject>(?<=subject=).*?(?=\s*(?:\w+=|spamscore|duration|virusname)))

Comment: Thanks @ctwheels  for the solution .

Answer (score 0):

You need to depend on **something**:
[`(?<=subject=)"?\K(.*?)(?=spam|virus|")`](https://regex101.com/r/4g0NvC/1)